# Get list of filenames in folder selected via FileDialog

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to extract the path of all the image files in a folder that is selected with a `FileDialog` with `selectFolder: true`.
All the examples I could find make use of a `FolderListModel` which gets the folder assigned statically.
I tried defining a temporary `FolderListModel` inside the dialog and change its `folder` property once I have the result from the dialog:

```
FileDialog {
    id: select_folder_dialog

    FolderListModel {
        id: mdl
        nameFilters: ["*.jpg", "*jpeg", "*.png"]
    }

    onAccepted: {
        visible = false
        var files = []
        console.log(folder)
        mdl.folder(folder)
        text1.text = qsTr("%1 images selected.".arg(mdl.count))
    }
    title: "Select a folder containing image file(s) to classify"
    selectFolder: true
}
```

This however gets me the error:

> Cannot assign object to property

I'm very confused. This seems to me a rather standard use-case (e.g. displaying in a list all the files in a user-defined folder), but I can't find any example.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is related to the way children `Item`s are treated in QML. Generally speaking each `Item` has a [`default` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties).

> A default property is the property to which a value is assigned if an object is declared within another object's definition without declaring it as a value for a particular property.

In the case of `Item` and `Item`-derived types such a property is [`data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) which

> allows you to freely mix visual children and resources in an item. If you assign a visual item to the data list it becomes a child and if you assign any other object type, it is added as a resource.

It's thank to `data` that you can e.g. mix and match `Timer`, `Rectangle` as well as other visible and not visible types inside an `Item`-derived type. Probably, the `default` property of `FileDialog` does not allow such degree of freedom. Hence, the solution it to *take out* `FolderListModel` from `FileDialog`, to avoid the error.

It should also be noted that simply assigning the `folder` property does not entitle the user to query the model. I/O operations can take time and model updates happen asynchronously. Thus, it is better to wait for appropriate events, e.g. `onFolderChanged`, to ensure that the model is ready to be queried. A resulting, *working*, example could look like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Window {
    title: qsTr("Test dialog")
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    FolderListModel {
        id: fileModel
        nameFilters: ["*.*"]

        onFolderChanged: { console.info(fileModel.get(0, "fileName")) }
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: dialog
        title: "Select a folder containing image file(s) to classify"
        selectFolder: true

        onAccepted: {
            dialog.close()
            fileModel.folder = folder
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: dialog.open()
}
```